# is there any way to adopt a memory resource for a vector?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, c++17, allocator

I have started using pmr::allocators in my project, and I have seen a lot of performance boost and advantage from using them. I use allocator very similar to what I show int the simple example below:

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MessageBody {
  using map_t = boost::container::flat_map<
      char, char, std::less<char>,
      std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::pair<char, char>>>;

  using vector_t = std::vector<char, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>>;

  MessageBody(std::pmr::memory_resource& mem_v,
              std::pmr::memory_resource& mem_m)
      : vec_(0, &mem_v), map_(&mem_m) {}

  vector_t vec_;
  map_t map_;
};

int main() {
  std::array<char, 1000> buffer;
  buffer.fill('\0');
  std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource vec_mem(buffer.data(), 500,
                                              std::pmr::null_memory_resource());
  std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource map_mem(buffer.data() + 500, 500,
                                              std::pmr::null_memory_resource());
  {
    MessageBody message(vec_mem, map_mem);
    message.vec_.push_back('1');
    assert(message.vec_.size() == 1);
  }

  {
    MessageBody message(vec_mem, map_mem);
    assert(message.vec_.size() == 1);   /// I want to adopt the previous class for a new class.
  }
}
```

my question is if there is any way I can adopt the `memory_resources` for another class without having the repopulate entire data inside `vector` and `map`.

the only way I can think of doing that (and I know it is a terrible idea), is to implement a new class that inherits from std::vector, that class has an adopt data method that set the `size` inside the vector to the size of the previously used vector without modifying the buffer.

here is a link to godbolt for the example.

https://godbolt.org/z/fcox5vTdE

Comment: I think you're better off using move construction to achieve this. Polymorphic allocators are just that, *allocators*. There's no expectation that they're some buffer to be interpreted when given to a container (aside, use `std::pmr::vector`)

Comment: @AndyG maybe I should've used a different example. imagine you are reading the buffer from a file or ther forms IO. then move is pretty much meaningless. you want to adopt the meory and use it if possible. similar idea like gsl::span for std::vector

Comment: @apramc The question states "for another class". This would seem to preclude reading from a file or other I/O. Wouldn't the sequence be: read from a file to the first class, then move the data from the first class to another class? With the question applying to the move rather than the read? You wouldn't have something to adopt until after the read is finished.

Comment: It seems I correctly intuited the use-case here. It's just not something that pmr allocators will do. One needs stateful allocators and Fancy Pointers [both of which are not supported by PMR](https://quuxplusone.github.io/draft/fancy-pointers.html). Sadly, but understandably. The purposes just don't align well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not to adopt the memory resource - because you can and do - but to *also store the vector itself there*.

You can, e.g. using a helper to create unique_ptr's with custom deleters:

```
template <typename T>
inline static auto make_T(Mem& mem) {
    std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T> alloc(&mem);
    return std::unique_ptr{
        alloc.template new_object<T>(), // allocator is propagated
        [alloc](T* p) { alloc.delete_object(p); }};
}
```

> It requires a bit more work when the library support for C++20 is not complete, so let me show that in a **live demo on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PbMa58bzr)**

However, there's no way you can "resurrect" a non-trivial type on the same memory using the C++ abstract machine model of memory.

### Live Objects In Buffers - Enter Boost Interprocess

What you really want is to store /live objects/ there and access them from somewhere else.

You can do this using shared-memory allocators, like from Boost Interprocess. You can do it on

- manually allocated buffer (like the monotonous memory resource)
- a managed shared memory segment
- a managed mapped file

Of course there's the benefit of persistence and multi-process access in the latter cases.

> If you don't need IPC or persistence, but like the managed segment abilities, use [`managed_external_buffer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_heap_memory_external_buffer)

### Demo Using Managed External Buffer

It takes a few typedefs to set up:

```
namespace Shared {
    using Mem = bip::managed_external_buffer;

    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor<
        bip::allocator<T, Mem::segment_manager>>;

    template <typename T>
    using Vector = boost::container::vector<T, Alloc<T> >;

    template <typename K, typename V, typename Cmp = std::less<K>>
    using Map =
        boost::container::flat_map<K, V, std::less<K>, Alloc<std::pair<K, V>>>;
} // namespace Shared
```

Note how I used the scoped_allocator_adaptor to get as close to PMR's behaviour of propagating the container allocator to element types according to `uses_allocator<>`.

```
struct MessageBody
{
    using map_t = Shared::Map<char, char>;
    using vector_t = Shared::Vector<char>;

    template <typename Alloc>
    MessageBody(Alloc alloc) : vec_(alloc), map_(alloc)
    { }

    vector_t vec_;
    map_t    map_;
};
```

No more unique_ptr required, your data structure is basically what you had, but we store everything in a single memory resource, so the whole thing can be "resurrected" as one:

```
int main() {
  std::array<char, 1000> buffer;
  buffer.fill('\0');

  {
      Shared::Mem mem(bip::create_only, buffer.data(), buffer.size());

      auto& message = *mem.find_or_construct<MessageBody>("message")(
          mem.get_segment_manager());

      message.vec_.push_back('1');
      assert(message.vec_.size() == 1);
  }

  {
      Shared::Mem mem(bip::open_only, buffer.data(), buffer.size());

      auto& message = *mem.find_or_construct<MessageBody>("message")(
          mem.get_segment_manager());

      assert(message.vec_.size() == 1);
  }
  std::cout << "Bye" << "\n";
}
```

The `get_segment_manager()` call returns a pointer that serves as the initializer for `Shared::Alloc<>` instances.

Now it runs passes the assert: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0805f5a9b5e8219)**

Just prints

```
Bye
```

Comment: Adding a demo of using [`managed_mapped_file` that adds persistence to the picture](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b288f02ab660b5b). Note how (a) it stores a vector of strings now, just to show off (b) it grows on each run of the program (c) the file is allocated sparsely (not visible, but you could pick a size like `10<<30` (10 gibibytes) and observe actual disk usage).

Comment: I hope the nice demo in the comment section doesn't go away. I might want to be able to find it later (and I really find the boost documentation troublesome). Great stuff!

Comment: @TedLyngmo That sample is really just my answer code but replacing `managed_external_buffer` with `managed_mapped_file`. If anyone needs it and it's gone, I'll type it up again :) Cheers