# Using hugepages with boost interprocess managed shared memory

Tags: c++, boost, ipc

I am using https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html (*boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory*) for a vector:

```
// Vector, SharedData typedefs
mempool_ = segment_.find_or_construct<Vector<SharedData>>((const char *) mempool_name_.c_str())(size_, segment_.get_segment_manager());
```

which works as expected, with `size_ = 32K` above. When I profile the memory access of the vector in several iterations,
I observe that access of contiguous elements across the vector is having latency jumps exactly at every 4KiB memory access! The default page size in OS being 4KiB. This is  certainly due to page faults occurring at the boundaries of next memory accesses.

To avoid these page faults at my latency sensitive use-case, I am trying to increase the page size of this shared memory segment by using **hugepages**.

I found a conversation in boost google group which is exactly related to this: https://groups.google.com/g/boost-developers-archive/c/bDSd9DOTbp0

A ticket is mentioned there which seems to be fixed: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/8030

But I cannot seem to find documentation on how to use *MAP_HUGETLB* flag for the managed_memory_segment.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The support for custom map options only exists for `mapped_region`. I analyze the code below.

You could still have your cake and eat it, by using `mapped_region` (e.g. on top of `shared_memory_object` or `anonymous_shared_memory`). You can then mount a `managed_external_buffer` on it to get a managed segment inside that custom mapping.

Perhaps considering the level of control you are after, you could just use the `mapped_region` directly.

## Code Dive

The commit lives as commit f9c10bd60d8a1ad30ebc7ef86ca5cb9184fbd966 in git:

The release notes for 1.54.0 say

```
*  Added support for platform-specific flags to mapped_region (ticket #8030)
```

The following documentation is found at `mapped_region`:

> The map is created using `default_map_options`. This flag is OS
> dependant and it should not be changed unless the user needs to
> specify special options.
>
> In Windows systems `map_options` is a `DWORD` value passed as
> `dwDesiredAccess` to `MapViewOfFileEx`. If `default_map_options` is
> passed it's initialized to zero. `map_options` is XORed with
> `FILE_MAP_[COPY|READ|WRITE]`.
>
> In UNIX systems and POSIX mappings `map_options` is an int value
> passed as `flags` to `mmap`. If `default_map_options` is specified
> it's initialized to `MAP_NOSYNC` if that option exists and to zero
> otherwise. `map_options` XORed with `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED`.
>
> In UNIX systems and XSI mappings `map_options` is an int value passed
> as `shmflg` to `shmat`. If `default_map_options` is specified it's
> initialized to zero.  `map_options` is XORed with `SHM_RDONLY` if
> needed.

### DEMO

In response to the comment made a simplified example using managed_external_buffer on top of mapped_region on top of shared_memory_object:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79d5ed67421479f8)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_external_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>

// demo only
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using Segment                  = bip::managed_external_buffer;
template <class T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Segment::segment_manager>;
using Data                     = bip::vector<double, Alloc<double>>;

struct MySharedSegment {
    MySharedSegment(bip::create_only_t, char const* name, size_t size)
        : _smo{bip::create_only, name, bip::mode_t::read_write} //
    {
        _smo.truncate(size);

        _buf  = bip::mapped_region(_smo, bip::mode_t::read_write, 0, size);
        _mb   = Segment(bip::create_only, _buf.get_address(), _buf.get_size());
        _data = _mb.construct<Data>("vec")(_mb.get_segment_manager());
        _data->reserve(1000);
    }

    MySharedSegment(bip::open_only_t, char const* filename)
        : _smo{bip::open_only, filename, bip::mode_t::read_write}
        , _buf{_smo, bip::mode_t::read_write}
        , _mb{bip::open_only, _buf.get_address(), _buf.get_size()} //
    {
        assert(_mb.get_size() <= _buf.get_size());

        auto [v, vok] = _mb.find<Data>("vec");

        if (!v || !vok)
            throw std::runtime_error("expected object was not found");

        _data   = v;
    }

    Data& data() {
        assert(_data);
        return *_data;
    }

    Segment::segment_manager* get_segment_manager() {
        return _mb.get_segment_manager();
    }

  private:
    bip::shared_memory_object _smo;
    bip::mapped_region        _buf;
    Segment                   _mb;
    Data*                     _data = nullptr;
};

int main(int argc, char**) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "First run, creating\n";
        bip::shared_memory_object::remove("SHM_NAME");

        MySharedSegment mss(bip::create_only, "SHM_NAME", 10 * 1024 * 1024);

        auto& db  = mss.data();

        db.emplace_back(1.1);
        db.emplace_back(2.2);
        db.emplace_back(3.3);
        std::cout << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Second run, opening\n";
        MySharedSegment mss(bip::open_only, "SHM_NAME");

        for (auto el : mss.data())
            std::cout << el << " ";

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Local demo:

[image]

Comment: I have some examples on this site using `managed_external_buffer` some of which use `mapped_region`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+managed_external_buffer

Comment: "You can then mount a managed_external_buffer on it to get a managed segment inside that custom mapping." - How can I mount a managed_external_buffer on top of an already created shared_memory_object and mapped_region? Can you please elaborate a little on this, thanks! I did go through the examples above, but I coulnd't understand exactly how.

Comment: I can not be more elaborate than with a concrete example. Let me pick from the last answer (sorted by date) that I had linked (except this one of course): https://godbolt.org/z/18Thq8qr4. The second one is a little more straightforward https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790900/85371. See the [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.shared_memory_creating_shared_memory_segments) on how to combine `shared_memory_object` and `mapped_region`.

Comment: I've stripped that first example of all unneeded complexity for this answer and added it http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79d5ed67421479f8