# Transparent hugepages not working with madvise

Tags: boost, shared-memory, huge-pages

I have been trying to use transparent hugepages in my application. For, this I have correctly configured my system with `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` set to `[madvise]`. I am allocating a mempool using boost::interprocess in `/dev/shm` and trying to later map this memory to hugepages using madvise. As can be seen in the snippet below :

```
int64_t ptr = (int64_t)mempool_;
ptr         = ((ptr >> 21) + 1) << 21;  // For aligning to hugepage boundary
int ret_val = madvise((void*)ptr, 2 * 1024 * 1024, MADV_HUGEPAGE);

cout << "start : "                     << (void*)ptr                     << endl;
cout << "end : "                       << (void*)(ptr + 2 * 1024 * 1024) << endl;
cout << "Return value of madvise() : " << ret_val                        << endl;
cout << "Errno  set to : "             << errno                          << endl;
cout << "Error on madvise: "           << strerror( errno )              << endl;
```

The output of this snippet is :

```
start : 0x7f2d17400000
end : 0x7f2d17600000
Return value of madvise() : 0
Errno  set to : 0
Error on madvise: Success
```

It, seems everything is right but hugepages are not allocated in my system. I do not understand why is this happening ?
I let my program run sufficiently long enough for khugepaged to get scheduled. For my system

scan_sleep_millisecs : 10000

alloc_sleep_millisecs: 60000

Comment: Why is boost in this picture? What is `mempool`? Because you're hard-reinterpret-C-style-casting it to `int64_t` and it looks extremely suspect. Just post a self-contained snippet to answer all these questions (and also make the boost tag relevant)

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply
`mempool_ = segment_.find_or_construct<char>("mempool")[4194304]();`
segment_ is a boost shared memory segment created using boost::interprocess

Comment: I'm really surprised you opting in for the overhead of `managed_shared_memory` (or `managed_mapped_file` or `managed_external_buffer`, you still didn't clarify...) and ... only allocate a big `char` array? Also, the return value of `find_or_construct` is a `offset_ptr`, which will indeed lead to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) with your C-style cast ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used))

Comment: `managed_shared_memory` is required for my application. Sorry, but I am not getting why using C-style cast would lead to UB.

Comment: My usecase is similar to the one mentioned [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74572697/using-hugepages-with-boost-interprocess-managed-shared-memory](here) but I wish to use transparent hugepages rather than normal hugepages.